# installation of linux in older windows based laptop

Tags: live-usb, playonlinux, linux-headers

Is it beneficial to install linux in the 7 years old windows based laptop.....I have been using hp g62 for so long but due to the heating issue I have to repair it and costing a lot for me every year. someone told me that it will run smooth on the linux. so please reply asap because I m going to purchase the new pc.

Comment: Maybe the following link will help you select a version and flavour of Ubuntu to try, [How to select the version and flavour of Ubuntu](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13540865#post13540865)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, yes you can run various flavors of Linux, also Ubuntu up to the latest version on your HP G62.

And yes, given the smaller profile and lower load (compared to Windows), it will perform well on your device. The notebook I'm using right now, is quite similar.

However, the operating system will NOT make your heat problem go away. So, you still need to deal with that first. And you can Google it and find manuals for that.

Personally, I would always suggest a lightweight GUI option. I would favor Mate, since it is leight in weight, stable, reliable and easy to use. Meaning, you might want to go with 64Bit Ubuntu Mate and you can use the latest 18.04.

Just download an ISO, create a live system and test it yourself to see, if you like it. You'll need a USB thumb drive to put your live system on and an application to get it done. Like USB installer. Then just boot from the USB drive and give it a go before you decide, if you want to install it ;)

If you know a few things about computers, creating the live system is not that hard. Otherwise, manuals are all around ;)